# How to Schedule a Task for a specific time in Windows IoT core Devices

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

I am using Windows IoT Core in  a gateway to run Services, now I want to run a PowerShell script that will perform a certain task in a specific time,

I know I can schedule a task on boot by using windows task scheduler

```
schtasks /create /tn "Startup PowerShell" /tr c:\Startup.bat /sc onstart /ru SYSTEM
```

Instead of the "onstart" if I want the task to be executed every day at 3 pm or sometimes, how I should write the scheduler

Answer (score 1):

`schtasks` is used to add and remove tasks from the schedule, start and stop tasks run periodically or at a specific time, and display and change scheduled tasks. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks).

The parameter `/st` is used to specify the time of day that the task starts (each time it starts) in  24-hour format. For example:

```
schtasks /create /tn <TaskName> /tr <TaskRun> /sc daily /st 15:00 /ru SYSTEM
```